# Shopware 6.5 Update "string:OPENSEARCH_URL" are never used

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am trying to Update to Shopware 6.5 from 6.4 and I am getting the following error message when running `composer require symfony/flex:~2 symfony/runtime:~6.2`:

`!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvParameterException: Environment variables "string:OPENSEARCH_URL" are never used.`

The error occurs while composer is running `assets:install` and the error is caused on `cache:clear` aswell.

Why does that occur and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't use elasticsearch I believe this problem also might disappear by not just requiring the `shopware/elasticsearch` module.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly obvious why that error occurs, but I couldn't reproduce it. Could it be, that you don't have `shopware/elasticsearch` installed? That package his [this configuration](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/fdffc13664b378754b65d152447f5213f11b207b/src/Elasticsearch/Resources/config/services.xml#L337) to avoid that error. However if that package wasn't installed, you should have no references to this parameter at all and as such no unused ones either.

Here's something you could try. Within the root directory of Shopware, navigate to `config/packages` and create a file `z-shopware.yaml`. Edit that file and insert the following content (make sure to keep the indentation as it is).

```yaml
parameters:
  some_dummy_parameter_for_usage: "%env(string:OPENSEARCH_URL)%"
```

This should count as usage of the environment variable and thus resolve the error. Also try to clear the cache manually once from inside the root directory: `rm -rf var/cache`

Comment: I have that variable referenced in elasticsearch.yaml. I removed that reference and now its working... Thats weird.